# Intervals denoted with bars

Tags: typography

Is it possible to reproduce overline with vertical bars at the ends for closed intervals in Latex? See the picture below.

[image]

Comment: off-topic: first time I see this notation. From where is the text?

Comment: It's from 'An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applicatioins' by William Feller, Vol. 2.John Wiley and Sons, 1971 (2nd edition), p. XV.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a set of macros that should do. The macro `\interval` has a two letter optional argument; if omitted, open is implied. Specifying only `o` or `c` is the same as `oo` and `cc` respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\interval}[2][oo]{%
  \mathord{\vbox{\offinterlineskip\m@th
    \ialign{##\cr
      \csname @interval#1\endcsname\cr
      $#2$\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\newcommand{\leaderbar}{%
  \mkern-7mu
  \cleaders\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle\mkern-2mu{\relbar}\mkern-2mu$}\hfill
  \mkern-7mu
}
\newcommand{\@intervaloo}{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle{\relbar}\leaderbar{\relbar}$%
}
\newcommand{\@intervalco}{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle{\mapstochar\relbar}\leaderbar{\relbar}$%
}
\newcommand{\@intervaloc}{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle{\relbar}\leaderbar{\relbar\mkern-1mu\mapsfromchar}$%
}
\newcommand{\@intervalcc}{%
  $\scriptscriptstyle{\mapstochar\relbar}\leaderbar{\relbar\mkern-1mu\mapsfromchar}$%
}
\let\@intervalc\@intervalcc
\let\@intervalo\@intervaloo
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\emph{Intervals} are denoted by bars: $\interval{a,b}$ is an open,
$\interval[cc]{a,b}$ is a closed interval; half-open intervals are
denoted by $\interval[oc]{a,b}$ and $\interval[co]{a,b}$.

\medskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\verb|\interval{a,b}| & $\interval{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[o]{a,b}| & $\interval[o]{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[oo]{a,b}| & $\interval[oo]{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[c]{a,b}| & $\interval[c]{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[cc]{a,b}| & $\interval[cc]{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[oc]{a,b}| & $\interval[oc]{a,b}$ \\
\verb|\interval[co]{a,b}| & $\interval[co]{a,b}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]